# How to get user input on click of a CommandBarControl item

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins, commandbar

I have a CommandBarControl and on the click of this control, I want to get a number as user input.

```
private void oControlHandler_Click(object CommandBarControl, ref bool Handled, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
//get a number as user input

//do some work on input
}
```

How to get user input?
I am using VS 2013 and .NET framework 4.0.

Comment: Where is your user typing in the user input?  Do you have another textbox on your screen or do you want to popup for them to use?

Comment: I would like to use a small pop up when user clicks on the control.

Comment: What type of app is this for, WinForms, WPF, specific add in?  Are you referring to the CommandBarControl in Office 2013? Of the Visual Studio CommandBarControl for extensions

Comment: It is a Visual Studio(2013 to be specific) Addin that gets shown on the right click at any place in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Windows Forms (or WPF) form with a control to enter the input, which can be a TextBox or some kind of NumericUpDown. Then, on the Click event you show the form modally (ShowDialog). Notice that your question is not related to Visual Studio add-ins.

Comment: thanks Carlos. I am going to create a dynamic form in WPF. Can you suggest some links for creating it in C#.